# How can I fire backspace event on keypress of space in a textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I don't want to simulate the effect of pressing backspace. I want the text field to delete the character, without manually manipulating the content of the textarea.

This is a sample. 
**Markup**

```
<textarea id="tex">sdfedasdgasg</textarea>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {

  var eventObj = document.createEventObject ? document.createEventObject() : document.createEvent("Events");
  if (eventObj.initEvent) {
    eventObj.initEvent("keydown", true, true);
  }
  eventObj.keyCode = 8;
  eventObj.which = 8;
  if (e.which === 32) {
    $('textarea').focus();
    var textField = document.getElementById('tex');
    textField.dispatchEvent ? textField.dispatchEvent(eventObj) : textField.fireEvent("onkeydown", eventObj);
  }

  if (e.which === 8) {
    console.log('bk');
  }
});
```

This detects the event, but the data is not getting updated. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is a rather odd requirement that sounds a lot like an XY problem. Could you explain exactly what you're trying to achieve as there may be a better way to do it.

Comment: What I have is a contenteditable, that will take in ascii emoticons [ :-), :-( ...] and replace those with emojis. So I want to do a backspace on the contenteditable(not modify the html, since that'll mess up the cursor location).

Comment: @mmativ:I meant the content of textarea.

Answer (score 0):

I put the solution here

https://jsfiddle.net/r6swvvew/

HTML

```
Spacebar is the new backspace
<BR>
<textarea id="sample"></textarea>
```

JQuery

```
$("#sample").keypress(function(e){
  if(e.keyCode == '32')
    {
    e.preventDefault();
    var len = $(this).val().length;
    var newval = $(this).val().substring(0, parseInt(len) - 1);
    $(this).val( newval );
  }
});
```

Comment: I dont want to manually update the textarea. I want the backspace event to update the textarea. Not this way `var newval = $(this).val().substring(0, parseInt(len) - 1);
    $(this).val( newval );`

Comment: See, what you're doing is `$("#sample").val( newval );`. This is manually updating the textarea. I want to dispatch a backspace event on hitting spacebar, which I tried to do in my code sample.

Comment: **I want to dispatch a backspace event on hitting spacebar**, Yes It is. Try it first. It's not manual, it's automatic once you hit the spacebar.

Comment: Not manually in the sense, not programmatically updating the value. If I follow your suggestion, and if I were to listen for backspace keypress event(don't want to),it wont fire, right?In my fiddle, if you open the console, you can see that while hitting spacebar and backspace, same message is logged. But character deletion is not happening on spacebar.

Comment: Character deletion is working on my screen on the fiddle I just posted. By the way, It may be the one you're looking for, [Maybe](http://jsfiddle.net/qtPcF/173/).

Comment: Hi, When I press spacebar,I'm getting the message, but character is not being deleted. This is the problem I'm facing.

Comment: Voted this down because this answer does not address the question. The question asks " I want the text field to delete the character, without manually manipulating the content of the textarea.". This answer does precisely the opposite to what the OP requested as it manipulates the value. The correct answer is that you can't do what the OP requests.